# Find Oracle database server from list of IP addresses

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, networking

Got a list of IP addresses (or IP range ), from this I need to find Oracle running system in a LAN network using C# code. Purpose of this is to keep log of Oracle running systems. How can I do this?

Comment: So you are trying to implement [Shodan.io](https://www.shodan.io) just to find Oracle databases...

Comment: but the search limited in my LAN network

Comment: Do you know if Oracle is running on the default port (`1521`) or do you need to port scan all the ports? Will any of the systems not running Oracle be running anything else on the same port as Oracle (i.e. can you just test if there is a response from port 1521 and that means Oracle is running or do you need to test if the response is Oracle and not some other application)?

Comment: I need to scan all ports, and want to make sure that the response is from oracle, not from any other application